# Swift: Unable to touch canvas view on scrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to build an image editing function in my app. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHujp-tbyOQ) to enable zooming capability and this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2NTCmEsdSE) for the drawing portion.

I am implementing the drawing portion and realised that the `canvas` view is not detecting the touches when it is overlaid onto a `scrollView`. The current hierarchy is as such:

```
scrollView -> imageView -> canvas
```

Implementation so far:

```
//At the viewController that implements the Canvas UIView
var imageView: UIImageView!
var canvas = Canvas()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    setupCanvas()
}

func setupCanvas() {
    imageView.addSubview(canvas)
    canvas.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    canvas.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: 3000)
    canvas.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

//At the Canvas class
class Canvas: UIView {

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {return}

        print("Moved", point) //Breakpoint here not called
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {return}
        print("Began", point) //Breakpoint here not called

    }        
}
```

At this moment, the touches seems to be interacting with the `scrollView`instead. Is there a way that detect the `touches` on the `canvas` view instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, elementary mistake. It should be

```
scrollView.addSubview(canvas)
```

instead.